# inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length 400 error in WCF header after sending a latin special character

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

I'm using WCF with .Net 4.0 with all the defaults for basicHttpBinding with security mode TransportWithMessageCredential over https.  When I make a web method call from the client sending a special character link **ñ** the method succeeds but every next method call gives a 404 error with no further information and in the trace log shows the following error:

> The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP
>   Content-Length header.  There may have been a network error or the
>   client may be sending invalid requests.

Because I am using the defaults the text encoding is utf-8.  I have tested on IIS7 and IIS7.5.  This same issue happens on my local machine with IIS Express.  It is unusual that the special character makes it to the server and is written successfully to the database and then WCF just kind of faults.  I have to reset the website for WCF to start working again on the server.

Here is the test code that fails:

```
using (ToursServiceClient client = new ToursServiceClient())
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";

    Tour tour = new Tour();
    tour.Customer = new Customer();
    tour.Customer.FirstName = "ñ";

    InsertTourResult insertTourResult = client.InsertTour(tour);
    Tour insertedTour = client.GetTourByTourID(insertTourResult.TourID);
}
```

This code fails on the call to:

```
client.GetTourByTourID(insertTourResult.TourID);
```

This code is successful if I change this line of code:

```
tour.Customer.FirstName = "ñ";
```

to:

```
tour.Customer.FirstName = "a";
```

Although I am using just the default bindings I will list them here for completeness:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ToursService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Tyler